# C# : Looping forever foreach CheckedListBox item

Tags: c#

```
foreach (CheckedListBox item in itemInfoCheckList.Items)
            {
                if (item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                    SW.WriteLine(item.Text + " :  YES");
                else
                    SW.WriteLine(item.Text + " : NO");
            }
```

THe above code snippet is where  it loops ... although there are only 2 items
Below is the iteminfochecklist definition

```
 this.itemInfoCheckList.CheckOnClick = true;
        this.itemInfoCheckList.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.itemInfoCheckList.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.itemInfoCheckList.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "item 1 ",
        "item 2"});
        this.itemInfoCheckList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(573, 350);
        this.itemInfoCheckList.Name = "itemInfoCheckList";
        this.itemInfoCheckList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 38);
        this.itemInfoCheckList.TabIndex = 143;
```

Comment: Please show us the code that defines / populates `itemInfoCheckList`. It is impossible to do anything other than conjecture given the loop alone.

Comment: That code is not going to go into an infinite loop.  How are you determining that it is?

Comment: Most probably you will get exception when you try to cast `itemInfoCheckList.Items` to `CheckedListBox`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this code

```
foreach (CheckedListBox item in itemInfoCheckList.Items)
```

use this code

```
foreach (Object item in itemInfoCheckList.CheckedItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also the methods GetItemChecked and SetItemChecked you can use like so:

```
CheckedListBox clb = (CheckedListBox)sender;
foreach (string item in clb.Items)
{
    bool isChecked = clb.GetItemChecked(clb.FindStringExact(item));
}
```